# Is it possible to invoke a lambda function without an api endpoint?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, invoke

I have a lambda function that creates a presigned url and I want to invoke that lambda function from my backend app.

I am using this code to invoke it from my backend app:

```
response = client.invoke(
   FunctionName=FunctionName,
   InvocationType='RequestResponse',
   LogType='None',
   Payload=json.dumps(payload)
)
```

but getting error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Invoke operation: 
User: arn:aws:iam::<user-id>:user 
is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: 
arn:aws:lambda:eu-east-1:<user-id>:function:function 
because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action
```

I have AWSLambdaRole permission to the user.

Is it possible to this, if yes then what might be the reason for Access Denied?

Comment: What exactly is `AWSLambdaRole`?

Comment: You don't have the permission as the message suggests - show us the roles/inline policies assigned to the user

Comment: Invoking AWS Lambda functions like you do is definitely possible, however as the other commenters already pointed out there is probably something wrong with the IAM permissions assigned to your backend app.